# Is Android Databinding really an all or nothing proposition?

Tags: java, android, json, kotlin, data-binding

As the title suggests, as near as I've been able to determine, when you use databinding with an android view I find that pretty much everything MUST be done using databinding.  Let me elaborate...

I followed a number of rather painful limitations when using databinding:

1. If I enable databinding on a view then setOnClick() listeners, added in code stop working; it seams I'm required to use databinding annotations to get calls for events.  This isn't so bad because it's easy to handle but still, an unexpected byproduct.
2. Setting image source from code also fails (quietly).  I have an ImageView which I set the image source  from a selected image in the gallery.  This code stopped working once I enabled databinding on the view.
3. 2-Way databinding with Kotlin data classes appears to not work (unless I add setters for all data properties I want to bind to.  Yes, I tried adding the @Bindable notation with no luck.  Since I use data classes for JSON this limitation is very big.  If I change to plain classes with setters then 2-way works but I loose the ability to use the Kotlin @Parcelize.
4. Somewhat related to the above; if my intention is to only use on-way databinding (which would still be useful) I find that one-way locks locally coded listeners(1) and setters(2).

I went through many examples, starting with [Data Binding Library in Jetpack](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/), the [Databinding Samples](https://github.com/android/databinding-samples) as well as the [Code Labs](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-databinding) with no answer but many frustrations.

Maybe someone who is more familiar with databinding in Android can confirm my investigations above and/or point me to something that might help.

I'd really like to use databinding as it has many benefits for data/UI management but without easy solutions to the above I find it simpler to move between UI/data classes using the old-fashion methods.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with ViewBinding in fact it's easier than Databinding, but the truth is that there is very limited documentation

Answer (score 0):

Databinding, in essence, is to avoid the usual findViewByIds, so enabling data binding will required that you use the data binding expressions along with the views (buttons, images, etc). If you enable data binding and use the usual import

```
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.what_ever_layout.*
```

The views will be null and your app will crash.

3. It makes sense if you have to use setters since you are reading properties from one end and updating it on another end. I am sure if your properties are mutable that is, var and you use the two-way binding expression &={} , everything should work.
4. if you need only one-way binding, then use [View Binding](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding)

Comment: Yes, I had this working (using the @={}) but with a kotlin data class only 1-way works unless I use a kotlin class with setters.  For example:

This: